# Disable to show selected symbole in <i> </i> tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button to open a dropdown menu. It looks like:

[image: Button]

But after clicking it, the `+` symbol appears selected, like the following:

[image: Button with selected text]

How can I remove selected area from plus symbol?

Find my code, using Bootstrap, in the snippet below:

```css
.custom-container {
  background-color: rgb(31, 182, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(31, 182, 255);
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}
.custom-dropdown {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap & jQuery CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Start of my code -->
<div class="custom-container">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle noselect custom-dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- End of my code -->
```

Comment: Can you format your code better and provide a jsFiddle please?

Comment: please use a fiddle/jsbin, place the styles outside of the html (inline style is never recommended, and it's hard to understand)

Comment: I formatted code , any other reason of downvoting ?

Comment: your code works fine. I dint face any problem.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recon right you can not use pseudo css, so you need to target your button from .css class or maybe  section.

```
.noselect::selection {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

I am sure that you can do It in more neat way, but this is first that comes in mind

```css
    .noselect::selection {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    }
```

```html
<p class="noselect">No select</p>

<p>Normal</p>
```

Comment: Sorry it's actually background not colour, made edits and example

Comment: yes it was background issue  I solved it by : to give `background-color: rgb(31, 182, 255);`  to anchor tag